# What is a singleton typed array?

Tags: javascript, singleton, emscripten

I'm trying to understand what is asm.js and what does it do, and I am reading this article here, by Alon Zakai: [What asm.js is and what asm.js isn't](http://mozakai.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/what-asmjs-is-and-what-asmjs-isnt.html)

He first talks about emscripten.js and explains that the pattern by which it compiles C++ to JS uses a singleton-typed array to make C++ feel at home in JS:

> That pattern involves using a **singleton typed array** to represent
>   memory (p. 7)

I know what a singleton object is and what the 'singleton pattern' looks like in Javascript, but what is a singleton-typed array? A Google search came up with nothing.

EDIT: I also do understand what Emscripten does and that pattern in question of implicitly-typed, but statically-typed variables (i.e. variables' types don't change throughout runtime), but still, the wording "singleton typed array" is beyond me.

Comment: Well, "singleton" means there's just one right? By reading the article it seems that's the point of that array. To have a **single** place to use as memory.

Comment: That's it? I half-hoped it was going to be something extraordinary. Silly me!

Comment: @pilau nevertheless amusing :)

Comment: @abergmeier We could sure use some comic relief in this community :P

Comment: @pilau Really. I thought I would ask enough stupid questions for this community to be hilarious ;)

Comment: @abergmeier I think we're competing for top position here :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It's not "singleton-typed array", but "singleton typed-array". Bah. I find English to be a vague language at certain areas. Here you go, curious ones: [Typed Arrays (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)